# Set size of div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with `id="test"` What I am trying to do is to resize the div to `body.clientHeight`-80px . So that the height of the element fills all the visible space on a browser window (without scrolling) except the 80px high header. I have js code as below:

```
let Height = document.body.clientHeight-80;
let myElement = document.getElementById("test");
myElement.style.height = Height;
```

The code will work fine if I use something like :`myElement.style.height = "600px";`.
I think the problem is that `document.body.clientHeight;` is returning a value without the unit px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate `"px"`

```
myElement.style.height = Height + "px";
```

and PS: use `const`, not `let`. Also preferably, if `Height` is not a Function that returns Methods (or a Class) use it as lowercase `height`.

### Use CSS, not JS

```
#test{
   height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
```

if *100vh* (Viewport Height) was your intention.

Example:

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

:root {
  --height-head: 80px;
}

#head {
  height: var(--height-head);
  background: #eee;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#test {
  height: calc(100vh - var(--height-head));
  background: #0bf;
}

#main {
  min-height: 60vh;
  background: #aaa;
}
#foot {
  min-height: 20vh;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="head">HEADER</header>
<div id="test">GALLERY calc(100vh - 80px)</div>
<main id="main">MAIN</main>
<footer id="foot">FOOTER</footer>
```